# select-based socket loop without polling

Tags: python, sockets

I'm having problems writing a thread that transfers data between IO buffers and a socket. I don't have any problems getting it to run, but not the way I want it to. Here's a sketch of the code:

```
s = socket(...) # some connection
in_buffer = b'' # consumed by other thread
out_buffer = b'' # produced by other thread
while True:
    (r, w, x) = select([s], [s], [s])
    if r:
        in_buffer += s.recv(RECV_LIMIT)
    if w:
        sent = s.send(out_buffer)
        out_buffer = out_buffer[sent:]
    if x:
        break
```

The problem with this is that it consumes a complete CPU when idle. The reason is that the socket is writable most of the time, in particular when idle. `select()` returns immediately, does nothing, calls `select()` again, does nothing etc. There's a simple fix, don't check for a writable socket when you don't have anything to write:

```
... # dito
while True:
    if out_buffer:
        (r, w, x) = select([s], [s], [s])
    else:
        (r, w, x) = select([s], [], [s])
    ... # dito
```

This works, but it has a different problem: When idle, this blocks on the `select()` infinitely. If I add something to the output buffer, I need to somehow wake up the thread from the `accept()` call, but how? For the record, my current workaround changes the evaluation slightly:

```
while True:
    (r, w, x) = select([s], [s], [s])
    if x:
        break
    elif r:
        in_buffer += s.recv(RECV_LIMIT)
    elif w:
        if out_buffer:
            sent = s.send(out_buffer)
            out_buffer = out_buffer[sent:]
        else:
            sleep(0.001)
```

In short, when there is really nothing to do, insert a delay. The millisecond is enough to not even consume 1% CPU. A similar approach would have been to use a timeout for the `select()` call and then re-check the presence of output data. Still, neither solution is good, since both effectively boil down to polling and polling sucks. So, how do I write an IO thread like this portably and without polling?

Note: One approach would be to add another filedescriptor on which I would create artificial traffic in order to wake up the thread from the blocking `select()` call. Here, the problem is that `select()` can only be used portably on sockets, not e.g. a pipe. Alternatively, on MS Windows, I could associate a win32 event with a socket's state changes and another event to wake up a thread (see [WSAEventSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), but I don't want to write this code on top of the nonportable WinSock API either.

Comment: The send-a-byte-on-a-socket-to-wake-up-the-thread trick works fine in my code.  You can do it under Windows too, if you use a TCP or UDP socket rather than a pipe.

Comment: You are suggesting creating a pair of loopback-sockets to wake up a thread. Yes, it surely works, no doubt about that. I'm pretty sure that it involves marshalling data from a process to the kernel's IP stack and back to the same process though, which is probably even slower than my current hack.

Comment: All I can say is that I use the technique all over the place in my (fairly performance-critical, C++ based) programs, and I've never noticed any slowdown because of it.  I think data-paths for sending data over the loopback device is pretty well-optimized, and you only need to send a single byte per wakeup in any case.  Given that your code is running inside a Python interpreter anyway, I don't think you'd notice any slowdown either.  (be sure to disable Nagle's algorithm though)

Comment: You are right, the performance cost is probably not noticeable. I still find it as unsatisfactory as my current workaround though, because it does things that simply should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear to me why you need to have this middleman in here working with `select` -- is this a constraint of your problem? It seems to me that if it is, then you have to treat the output buffer as a resource that needs to be ready for reading before you even tell select that you're interested in writing.

It seems like this would be much simplified if you switched your buffers with [`Queue`s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue) of little strings that get passed along. That way, you can have two threads that interact with the socket:

```
# One Thread consuming the socket
while True:
    (r, w, x) = select([s], [], [s])
    if r:
        in_buffer.put(s.recv(RECV_LIMIT))
    if x:
        break

# And one Thread writing to the socket
while True:
    string = out_buffer.get()
    (r, w, x) = select([], [s], [s])
    if w:
        s.send(string)
    if x:
        break
```

That way the producing thread can safely signal that data's even ready to be written. That said, `select` is a really low-level interface (as is `socket`, for that matter), and I would consider using an abstraction that knows a few more bells and whistles. I'm partial to [gevent](http://www.gevent.org), but of course it's geared towards IO-bound applications and may not be a good fit if you're CPU-bound. There the producers and consumers can efficiently interact with the socket directly, removing the need for this middleman:

```
import gevent
from gevent import socket, sleep

def producer(sock):
    # We'll spit out some bytes every so often
    while True:
        sock.send('Hello from the producer!')
        sleep(0.01)

def consumer(sock):
    # We'll read some in as long as we can
    buffer = ''
    while True:
        buffer += sock.recv(100)
        # If the buffer can be consumed, we'll consume it and reset
        if len(buffer) > 500:
            print 'Consuming buffer: %s' % buffer
            buffer = ''

def client(sock):
    # This will emulate a client that prints what it recieves, but always
    # sends the same message
    while True:
        sock.send('Hello from the client!')
        print sock.recv(100)

# Run this to get the server going
listener = socket.socket()
listener.bind(('127.0.0.1', 5001))
listener.listen(5)
(sock, addr) = listener.accept()
gevent.joinall([
    gevent.spawn(producer, sock),
    gevent.spawn(consumer, sock)
])

# Run this to get a client going
connector = socket.socket()
connector.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5001))
gevent.joinall([
    gevent.spawn(client, connector)
])
```

Comment: I think you make a very good point here, going to a higher level framework. I'll have to research about gevent a bit and see what it does. Unfortunately, it doesn't support Python 3 yet, although support is on its way. Another thing that I'm wondering about is whether using the same socket in two select()s is guaranteed to work, I haven't found a definite answer yet. Lastly, it still bothers me that there doesn't seem to be a clean solution using the tools Python comes with.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point about Python 3. It seems that calling select from two threads isn't expressly prohibited, but it might be best to have the exception checking in one thread but not both. That would seem to simplify one of the listening threads. That said, it seems to me you're always waiting for two events: data being produced and data available on the socket. If using threading, to me that implies two threads with one listening for each. I think the first snippet is reasonably clean given the problem and it does only use python core modules :-)

Comment: When using two threads, there is still the problem that I'm using the same socket in two threads, even if one is only writing while the other is only reading. Further, when I want to close the connection, I still need a way to wake up the two. For the one writing, putting a signal value into the queue is easy. The one waiting in the accept isn't, closing the socket to wake the thread is again a use from multiple threads and also questionable. That said, I disagree with you, two events doesn't imply two threads to me. I'd rather say that servicing one resource (socket) implies one thread. YMMV.

Comment: It is totally legitimate to use a single thread, but it's not really a single resource -- you have the socket, _and_ a producer. With the details of the producer unavailable, it's hard to say whether it could be intermingled into a single select well. The problem is you want to woken up when 1. data is available to read, or 2. data is available to write _and_ the socket is ready to be written to. If you could treat your producer as a file descriptor, then you could easily use a single select, but otherwise, you need a way to interface with the producer to catch that event.